# find files that do not match today date batch

Tags: batch-file

I need to find files that don't match today's date for date modified.
Below is the code for single file. Can any one suggest batch program to check the same for multiple files in a folder.

```
@ECHO OFF

echo %date%
pause

FOR %%a IN (D:\Study\Test\myfile.txt) DO SET FileDate=%%~ta
 set DATEONLY=%FileDate:~0,10%
 echo %DATEONLY%
 pause

if %DATEONLY%==%date% (
  echo date ok
) 
else (
  ECHO     Wrong
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: `FOR %%a in (D:\Study\Test\*.txt) DO (`

Comment: forfiles /D -1 /m "*.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Using your current script, simply say `*.txt` and you should use `delayedexpansion`:

```
@echo off
echo ***Current %date%***
pause>nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%a IN (D:\Study\Test\*.txt) DO (
 SET FileDate=%%~ta
 set DATEONLY=!FileDate:~0,10!
 REM echo !DATEONLY!
 pause>nul

if !DATEONLY!==!date! (
  echo OK: %%a !DATEONLY! = !date!
) else (
  echo INCORRECT: %%a !DATEONLY! not !date!
)
)
pause>nul
```

If it is to check **all** files in a folder, and not only `*.txt`

```
FOR %%a IN (D:\Study\Test\*.*) DO (
```

I have also added `>nul` in the `pause` command areas, as it will get rid of the annoying `press any key` outputs